# Q: Understanding subdirectories via base href in Angular 2 (with angular-cli)

Tags: angular, angular-cli

**TL;DR**: Where is the app root folder in an Angular 2 application? How can i equally deploy my application with `ng build` and run/develop it via `ng serve` while using a subdirectory?

---

*This questions is for Angular >=2.4 using Webpack not the AngularJS2 alpha-beta-whatever. I do also use [angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.26](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/v1.0.0-beta.26/CHANGELOG.md) not @angular/cli in the following example.*

There are already some questions regarding `<base href="...">` at stackoverflow but i don't think i did understand the solution or my question has been properly answered.

**Example**

I have a project where my application is deployed on a webserver in the directory `sub/`. The `<base>`-element of the application is of course  `<base href="/sub/">`. The project structure has been generated by angular-cli like this (please don't be picky about the '/')

```
project/
--src/
----app/
------app.module
----assets/
----index.html
----[...]
```

When i build the project via `ng build` and copy the result from the `dist/` folder to my webserver (to `sub/`) the app runs just fine at `mydomain/sub/` . When i try to run the app via `ng serve` it don't seem to be able to find the correct command to get the application to run at `localhost/sub/`. Neither editing any of the configuration files nor using the `-lrbu` flag seem to have an effect on my build.

The [official docs/tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) state/s

> If the app folder is the application root, as it is for the sample application, set the href value exactly as shown here.
>   `<base href="/">`

The **first questions** that arises: *Where is the app root folder?*

I assume that the application root is the `src/` directory as i configured in my `application-cli.json` but i don't know that for sure because the app folder could be `app/` as well.

What i then tried was to change the directories while adding an actual `sub/` folder like

```
project/
--src/
----sub/
------app/
--------app.module
----assets/
----index.html
```

or

```
project/
--src/
----app/
------sub/
--------app.module
----assets/
----index.html
```

and edited some `*.config.json` files with interesting effects. One of the variations got my application working with `ng serve` as desired but "broke" my deployment 'cause `ng build` would produce something like

```
dist/
--sub/
----assets/
----index.html
--main.bundle.js
--inline.bundle.js
--[...]
```

The result was okay for me though i'd like to have the javascript chunks in my `sub/` directory. This can be done with changing the `outDir` property in `application-cli.json` but yet again breaks `ng serve` or results in

```
dist/
--sub/
----sub/
------assets/
------index.html
----main.bundle.js
----inline.bundle.js
----[...]
```

Right now i really can't remember what got it working for me but i'd like to know what the correct solution for this problem is.